# Move tkinter label using button command

Tags: python, class, tkinter, label

I am trying to recreate the boardgame monopoly using python and tkinter. I know how to place a label on a canvas or a frame, but how should I do this command is being run from another function in the class? I tried it using some function within the class Board, but then the error rises that the label, canvas, etc. are not defined as this happens in `__init__(self,parent)`. How can I solve these errors? Or should I take a different approach to this? Hope I made my problem clear.

```
import tkFileDialog
from random import randint

class Board(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):


        ##create the board
        frame = Frame(parent)
        frame.pack()
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        frame2 = Frame(frame)
        frame2.pack()

        c=Canvas(frame2,width=480,height=480)
        c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
        c.background=PhotoImage(file='Board.gif')
        c.create_image(0,0,image=c.background,anchor='nw')

        ##Add player 1
        player1=PhotoImage(file='plane.gif')
        label_player1 = Label(c,image=player1)
        label_player1.image=player1
        label_player1.place(x=430,y=420)

        ##Add player 2
        player2=PhotoImage(file='car.gif')
        label_player2 = Label(c,image=player2)
        label_player2.image=player2
        label_player2.place(x=430,y=450)

        button = Button(frame, text="Next turn", command=self.next_turn)
        button.pack()

        button = Button(frame, text="Roll the dice", command=self.roll)
        button.pack()

    def roll(self):
        number=randint(2,12)
        if b==0:
            self.place_player_down()
        return number

    def place_player_down(self):

        for i in range(number+1):
            h=int(430-i*30)
            while h>=0:
                player2=PhotoImage(file='car.gif')
                label_player2 = Label(c,image=player2)
                label_player2.image=player2
                label_player2.place(x=h,y=420)

root = Tk()
board = Board(root)
board.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is correct (wrap your Tkinter widgets in a class with the event handler functions as methods), but you forgot to set the widgets as attributes of the class using the reference to `self`:

```
class Board(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        # ...
        self.c = Canvas(frame2,width=480,height=480)
        self.c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
        # ...

    def place_player_down(self):
        # Use 'self.c', not just 'c'
```

I think you want to do something similar with the value `number`, but it that case I would send it as an argument to `place_player_down`:

```
def roll(self):
    number=randint(2,12)
    if b==0:
        self.place_player_down(number)
    return number  # Keep in mind that this value is returned but not used anymore

def place_player_down(self, number):
    # Use 'number'
```

Comment: This actually worked. Setting almost everything in __init__ to self.'' made it work. Thanks a lot!